# Converting 23/Oct/2014 to 2014/10/23 in Python

Tags: python, date, python-3.x

I have date strings in the form of `'23/Oct/2014'` and want to convert it to `'2014/10/23'` in Python 3. The final output I need is just as a string. I implementing my own function to do the conversion using dictionary (for month conversion) but I am wondering if there is more pythonic way of doing the same thing.

Comment: Your own dict method would be fine and more efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`datetime` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to parse the string, then format back to a string again:

```
from datetime import datetime

converted = datetime.strptime(original, '%d/%b/%Y').strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

This parses the input string using [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), then formats the resulting object to a string again with [`datetime.datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime).

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> original = '23/Oct/2014'
>>> datetime.strptime(original, '%d/%b/%Y').strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
'2014/10/23'
```

Comment: @TankorSmash: sorry for the conflicting edit, but I am not sure why your edit was needed.

Comment: No worries. You just had the implied variable `original`, and I wanted to make it, and the output, more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a string, your dict mapping and format would work fine, if you don't want datetime objects I don't see the point in using datetime:

```
dt = '23/Oct/2014'
dates = dict(Jan="01", Feb="02", Mar="03", Apr="04", May="05", Jun="06", Jul="07", Aug="08", Sep="09", Oct="10",
             Nov="11", Dec="12")
day,mon, year = dt.split("/")
print("{}/{}/{}".format(year,dates[mon],day))
2014/10/23
```